# input="date" invalid value in database after save

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

After picking date from input type="date", date-picker, it is wrongly stored into database.

I'm picking the date from datepicker and then using AngularJS sending it to Spring MVC

angularJS:

```
$scope.updateProjectDetails = function(detail) {
    $http.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/details', detail)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```

chrome console:

```
config: {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), paramSerializer: ƒ, url: "/editor-application/api/details", …}
data:
date: 1557439200000
hours: 2
id: 76
projectId: 53
```

> 1557439200000 -> 5/10/2019, 12:00:00 AM

Then JSON is posted to MVC mechanism:

controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/details")
public ProjectDetails updateProjectDetails(@RequestBody ProjectDetails details) {

    details.setId(0);
    editorService.updateProjectDetails(details);
    return details;
}
```

dao:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateProjectDetails(ProjectDetails details) {

    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(details);
}
```

and database:

> 76    2019-05-09  2   53

Date is always -1 day, I know there is an issue of timezone, but how should I address it?

Comment: `1557439200000` = (GMT) Thursday, May 9, 2019 10:00:00 PM. Why would you expect a different time?

Comment: to UTC time & date:
Thu May 09 2019 22:00:00, 
to local time & date:
Fri May 10 2019 00:00:00

Comment: But you did not include any time zone offset or location identification. Because of that lack of detail, GMT (or UTC) is assumed. You will need to offset for your location or convert date strings to UTC and set your DB to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found the following works:

```
// from the server
$http.get('myDate').then(date => // date === 1557439200000
    new Date(date-(new Date(date).getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)).toISOString().slice(0,10)
)
```

It's a bit of boilerplate, but gets the job done.